# Jenkins- periodical poll and parametrized build

Tags: git, jenkins

I currently have a job in jenkins that polls a git repository every 5 minutes and builds if there were any changes.

I wanted to add a parametrized build option, so that I can manually run a build for a specified commit hash.
My idea is that the job works as it does now (polls for changes and builds) plus allows me to trigger a manual build for a specific commit SHA (inputted by hand).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried it already? What is your experience, what errors or problems do occur?

Comment: I had an idea to simply add a parameter to the job that contains the SHA and do a checkout before building. I'm not sure if it won't interfere with the poll building, that's what my question was actually about.

Comment: HEAD? or you could add a new step which determines if a commit id is given and uses a slightly different logic, as if it is not given?

Comment: My idea was to add an additional Windows Batch step and run a checkout only if the parameter isn't empty and leave the rest of the building proces as it is

Comment: why a windows batch? like said, add a new step doing this. you could do this as a batch, but there is no real need for this.

Comment: It seems to work so far, but there is a problem. My last polled build number was 20, my manual build was 21. When I poll the SCM, Jenkins "thinks" it built the revision in build 21, despite it being a manual one and the actual poll build was 20.